# Can a method return more than one value?

Tags: c#

So I was wondering if a method can return more than one value?
I am trying to write a program which returns the lowest and greatest value of an array:

```
    public int GetMinMaxValue(int[] numbers)
    {
        int lowest;
        int greatest;

        foreach (int item in numbers)
        {
            // some code assigning the values
        }

        return lowest; // and is it possible to return greatest too?
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer is simply **No**, you can not send more than one parameter using `return` statement.

but logically **YES** by using parameter modifier `out`.

The `out` keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. To use an out parameter, both the method definition and the calling method must explicitly use the out keyword.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx):

> Although variables passed as out arguments do not have to be
>   initialized before being passed, the called method is required to
>   assign a value before the method returns.

So before leaving the function you should assign the values for both `lowest` and `greatest` parameters and if you don't intialize them ofcourse compiler warn you.

Try This:

```
public int GetMinMaxValue(int[] numbers,out int lowest,out int greatest)
{
    lowest=0; //not required if there is a definite assignment happens in your code
    greatest=0;//not required if there is a definite assignment happens in your code
    foreach (int item in numbers)
    {
        // some code assigning the values
    }

}
```

You can call above method as below:

```
int lowest; //not assigned to any value
int greatest;//not assigned to any value
GetMinMaxValue(numbers,out lowest,out greatest)
```

once after calling the above method your `lowest` and `greatest` variables will have the values assigned by `GetMinMaxValue()` method.

Comment: You can even omit the initialization of variables that are used as out arguments. As they are results of the method, this counts as initialization.

Comment: @Georg: You are absolutly right, but in OP's code i have not seen any definite assignment `(we are not sure wether foreach gets executed or not)` and the out parameters should be assigned to some value before quiting the function hence for safty i have assigned values :)

Comment: @Sudhaker Tillapudi In the method body this is absolutely correct. I meant the call of GetMinMaxValue. There, you don't have to initialize the variables. In the method body, you have to initialize lowest and greatest, otherwise you will get a compiler error

Comment: @Georg: sorry dear yes i observed that and updated my code, its not required.

Comment: @dcastro: sorry i overlooked Georg comment i meant was assigning the variables in method is required.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a number of ways to do it:

- Return an array,
- Return a `Tuple<T1,T2>`
- Return a custom class that you define for the purpose of returning several things from a method
- Use `out` or `ref` parameters.

In the first three cases you return a single object, but you stuff multiple values in it. In the last case you do not return a value at all, relying on an alternative way of passing the data back to the caller.

Comment: The answer is "No" and the ways to get around it is with a object that store several information.

Comment: @OrelEraki That's splitting hairs: for all practical purposes, returning an object with two values is as good as returning two values.

Comment: Sorry but i disagree, In basic it's all boils down to 1 object and 1 alone. A fix to your answer, will be the right thing to do because i think rather then the first line the answer is excellent, We here to teach but sometimes we mistaken also.

Answer (score 0):

No.

**But**, return type doesn't have to be a primitive number.
You can return a List/Array of objects, Or you can return a object which has several properties inside of it.